# Am a bit confused with dataSnapS nohot in firebase,

Tags: multithreading, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I have this app am working on, I want to show some items in the listview but am confused when I came across dataSnapShot while going through the firebase instructions, please I want to know does the snapshot of a database while reading in listview collect all items from the path I want to read,
Eg, I have a path name users and under it I have Jerry,Tom,Micheal,Victor,Williams, etc, under each user are files like age,name, picture,gender

Eg

```
User 
  Jerry:
        Name:
        Age:
        Picture:
  Tom:
      Name:
      Age
      Picture

   Micheal:
      Name:
      Age:
      Picture:
   Etc
```

Now,if I want to get at position with Name of the User  at a time will the dataSnapShot of User contain all the data in the user file path

Answer (score 0):

If you read a given path from the database, the snapshot contains all data from that path and below.

So if you read `/User/Jerry` from your structure, the snapshot contains Jerry's `Name`, `Age` and `Picture`.

If you read `/User`, the snapshot will contain `Name`, `Age` and `Picture` for all  users.

Comment: Thanks alot, but does the snapshot have less space while read or it still thesame space it covers when downloading

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean there with "space". Can you clarify, or even better: add a code sample of what you're trying to do to your question (there's an `edit` link right under it)?

Comment: Space like kilobytes, magat

Comment: Space I mean here is kilobytes magabyte etc

Comment: As said in my answer: If you read a given path from the database, the snapshot contains all data from that path and below. So that's the space it then uses, both in download size as in memory usage.